How to capture array values from a HTTP JSON response payload using JMeter PostProcessor and create/write it in a new CSV file?
I need to create a new CSV file by capturing 100s of array values retured as part of a JSON response Payload.
My response payload for a GET call:
{ "total": 5, "limit": 5, "results": [ 1273614, 1298245, 1298246, 1298247, 1298248 ] }
I need to capture what's within the "results" array (e.g., 1273614, 1298245, 1298246, ...) and create a csv file (e.g., userId.csv).
Thank you in advance.
I found one of the post (Click Here) which seems to have a solution, but my response payload is different than what's in the original post.
I tried below:
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).results.each { entry -> new File('userId.csv') << entry.get('results') << System.getProperty('line.separator') }
Apologies for mistakes in my code above, I am rusty with my coding skills.


Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns the above JSON

Put the following code into "Script" area:
new File('userId.csv').withWriter { writer ->
    new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).results.each { userId ->
        writer.write(userId + System.getProperty('line.separator'))
    }
}



More information:

Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?


Hi Ivan!
I tried the code you provided, but I am not able to get it working.
The "userId" in your code is not in the response payload, so how does the script recognize it?
Also, I reckon the csv file will be generated inside the /bin/ folder of the Jmeter?
Regards!

Your "not able to get it working" statement doesn't provide enough information to guess what you could do wrong, take a look at jmeter.log file, normally if JSR223 script fails somewhere somehow there should be a corresponding entry with the error message.
